# fat free framework class not loading after update

Tags: php, classloader, fat-free-framework

I just made an update to the latest version after an year and my classes no longer load outside classes folder. After update I kept the old index.php and config.php files.

I have a batch folder in root where I run my background scripts. To connect it with the framework I was using

```
require __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
```

and to load my class from classes/ext

```
$c = new \ext\ExampleClass();
```

The problem is that the script dies without error or anything when it gets to this line. Before was working without problems.

Thanks

Comment: Did you set AUTOLOAD? Otherwise F3 won't look into any folder to automatically load classes. On what version have you been before?

Comment: It was 3.0.3 and the AUTOLOAD is set on 'classes/'. Everything works correctly except the 'batch' folder which is set outside 'classes'. Within 'classes' folder I can call classes, but not outside it. It is something with 'base.php' file. Still digging

Comment: Well, then add the other folder to it. set('AUTOLOAD', 'classes/;batch/')

Comment: still not working. There are no classes inside batch anyway. So there is nothing to autoload. There are some scripts that call some classes and running them

Comment: That won't work. F3's autoload is only able to load classes having the same name as their files they're in.